# How to overflow/word-wrap numbers in table columns?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

How do I word-wrap the numbers in my columns?

[image: overflow]

Here I've got a `tabular` environment within a `table` environment (the latter for captions). Elsewhere I use `longtabu`s without a `table` environment, and would like to word wrap in both scenarios.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{2\tabcolsep}
\addtolength\mylen{\arrayrulewidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|%
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen-\arrayrulewidth}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.10\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.10\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.06\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.06\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.10\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.10\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen}|} 
     \hline
     \textbf{h} & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} &
     \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f} & \textbf{g} &
     \textbf{h} & \textbf{i} & \textbf{j} & \textbf{k} \\
     & & & & & & & & & & & \\
     \hline
```

Then the actual row:

```
     & 2.072779 & 0.843488 & 0.877791 & 78.0 & 11.0 & 80.0 
     & 23.0 & 0.697509 & 0.772277 & 0.879121 & 0.003292 \\
```

and finally:

```
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of streamlining and simplifying your code. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Is it really useful to allow linebreaks within numbers? In order to make sure, your table fits into the textwidth, you could reduce the fo t size, and adjust the value of tabcolsep.

Comment: Unrelated to the current issue but please be aware that the tabu package (that you use for longtabu) is currently unmaintained and can result in some undesired behavior: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: @leandriis - Yeah I know that's why I'm trying to stick to `tabularx`; but ended up needing a longtable. -  In terms of is it useful… yes it is. These are the real numbers; I suppose everything after the decimal could be made a much smaller font… or it could just overflow. - I've almost converted all my Word to LaTeX, and the overflow was a "feature" of Word's tables.

Comment: If you just want to use X type columns in a table that can break across pages, you could use the xltabular package. Regarding the table itself: do you use the geometry package in your actual document? If so, could you please include the corresponding settings in your question? Depending o the overall size of the table, e.g. the number of rows, either rotating the table to a landscape page or transposing it might be alternatives to introducing linebreaks within numbers.

Comment: Happy to use anything included in the latest TeXlive. I don't use geometry currently, and my page size is a4. The real table has 10 or 11 columns. I tried rotating and landscaping it, but neither worked well for this dataset.

Comment: Hmmmm,  url package?

Comment: @AT, any news? Does no one receive answer deserve to be upvoted or even accepted?

Comment: @Zarko - Whoops! - I was planning to try out the answers for my use case then I think this got lost in a tab. - Upvoted both answers and set one as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the following does not directly answer the question "how to enable linebreaks inside of numbers in table cells", the following layout based on `landscape` from the `pdflscape` package could be an alternative:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}} 
     \hline
     \textbf{h} & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} &
     \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f} & \textbf{g} &
     \textbf{h} & \textbf{i} & \textbf{j} & \textbf{k} \\
     \hline
  & 2.072779 & 0.843488 & 0.877791 & 78.0 & 11.0 & 80.0 
     & 23.0 & 0.697509 & 0.772277 & 0.879121 & 0.003292 \\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{13}{c}} 
     \toprule
     \textbf{h} & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} &
     \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f} & \textbf{g} &
     \textbf{h} & \textbf{i} & \textbf{j} & \textbf{k} \\
     \midrule
  & 2.072779 & 0.843488 & 0.877791 & 78.0 & 11.0 & 80.0 
     & 23.0 & 0.697509 & 0.772277 & 0.879121 & 0.003292 \\
     \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

---

If you insist on allowing linebreaks, you can make use of the `seqsplit` package as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{2\tabcolsep}
\addtolength\mylen{\arrayrulewidth}

\usepackage{seqsplit}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|%
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen-\arrayrulewidth}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.10\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.10\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.06\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.06\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.10\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.10\linewidth-\mylen}|
     p{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-\mylen}|} 
     \hline
     \textbf{h} & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} &
     \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f} & \textbf{g} &
     \textbf{h} & \textbf{i} & \textbf{j} & \textbf{k} \\
     & & & & & & & & & & & \\
     \hline
       & \seqsplit{2.072779} & \seqsplit{0.843488} & \seqsplit{0.877791} & \seqsplit{78.0} & \seqsplit{11.0} & \seqsplit{80.0} 
     & \seqsplit{23.0} & \seqsplit{0.697509} & \seqsplit{0.772277} & \seqsplit{0.879121} & \seqsplit{0.003292} \\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split a number digits on several lines is not very smart idea, in my opinion it is better to split and transpose table:

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

With use of the `tabularray` package and its libraries, which call `booktabs` and `siunitx` package, the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{2-Y}, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[c, si={table-format=2.6}] |
                        Q[c, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[c, si={table-format=2.6}]
                        },
             }
     \toprule
h   &    2.072779   &   f   &   23.0        \\
a   &    0.843488   &   g   &    0.697509   \\
b   &    0.877791   &   h   &    0.772277   \\
c   &   78.0        &   i   &    0.879121   \\
d   &   11.0        &   j   &    0.003292   \\
e   &   80.0        &       &               \\
     \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
you may split table on more parts, for example on four. In this case the table height is the same as at splitting numbers digits on three lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{2-Y}, vline{1-Y}=solid,
             colspec = {*{4}{Q[c, font=\bfseries]
                             Q[c, si={table-format=2.6}] |}
                        },
             }
     \toprule
h   & 2.072779  & c & 78.0  & f & 23.0      & i & 0.879121   \\
a   & 0.843488  & d & 11.0  & g &  0.697509 & j & 0.003292   \\
b   & 0.877791  & e & 80.0  & h &  0.772277 &   &           \\
     \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]